# Why import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; is not working after spring boot upgrades?

Tags: cucumber, test-runner

I upgrade spring boot version 2.2.0.RELEASE to 2.7.4. After that import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber; is not supported. This is the code,

```
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.json.support.Status;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.presentation.PresentationMode;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

/**
 * Class to generate html report from cucumber runner's json report output.
 */
public class CucumberReportRunner extends Cucumber {

  private static final String PROJECT_NAME = "Hello Cucumber & Spring Boot";
  private static final String BUILD_NUMBER = "1.0.0";
  private static final String BRANCH_NAME = "master";

  public CucumberReportRunner(Class clazz) throws InitializationError {
    super(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
    super.run(notifier);
    generateReport();
  }

  public static void generateReport() {

    File reportOutputDirectory = new File("target/html");
    List<String> jsonFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    jsonFiles.add("target/cucumber-report.json");

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(reportOutputDirectory, PROJECT_NAME);
    configuration.addPresentationModes(PresentationMode.RUN_WITH_JENKINS);
    configuration.setNotFailingStatuses(Collections.singleton(Status.SKIPPED));
    configuration.setBuildNumber(BUILD_NUMBER);
    configuration.addClassifications("Build Number", configuration.getBuildNumber());
    configuration.addClassifications("Branch Name", BRANCH_NAME);

    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonFiles, configuration);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
  }
}
```

In the code ,

**extends Cucumber**

**import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;**

**@Override
public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
super.run(notifier);**

code lines are shown in error.

and terminal getting this error,

```
/workspase/test-project/src/test/java/com/textile/bdd/CucumberReportRunner.java:3: error: package cucumber.api.junit does not exist
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
                         ^
/workspase/test-project/src/test/java/com/textile/bdd/CucumberReportRunner.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public class CucumberReportRunner extends Cucumber {
                                          ^
  symbol: class Cucumber
/workspase/test-project/src/test/java/com/textile/bdd/TestRunner.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
         ^
  symbol: class Cucumber
```

**What would be the best possible options?**

Comment: You've updated a dependency, now your dependencies don't work any more. Have you tried using `mvn dependency:tree` to see what has changed?

Comment: And maybe start over from scratch. Lots has changed in both Spring and Cucumber.  https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje this is a dependency tree,

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J-PJq55JolEFY8XFwuhiz-8o_otafVk_?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like you've been upgrading multiple dependencies at once. When you upgrade a dependency you should upgrade 1 major version at a time and before doing so read the release notes of that project. You can not change things and expect them to keep working. The only thing I can tell you to do is to start over from scratch with the latest versions and go through the documentation again.